# Does 2nd Peter have extant manuscripts that are a combination of Greek and Aramaic?

Tags: greek, history, 2-peter, aramaic, manuscript

I heard from somewhere (I cannot recall) that the extant manuscripts of *2nd Peter* were written in a combination of Aramaic and Greek, **is there any evidence for this?**

Example: (1 particular manuscript has both Greek and Aramaic on the same papyrus sheet).

(I’m **not** speaking about the autographs of scripture).

Comment: @Dottard Am I then thinking of the 5th century Peshitta translation?

Comment: I cannot tell what you are thinking.  However, the Peshitta and Aramaic translations came about the end of the 2nd century and third centuries

Comment: @Dottard And would that imply that 2nd Peter was likely in that loop of an Aramaic translation during the 2nd and 3rd centuries?

Comment: This should be the subject of a separate question.  However, the oldest Syriac MSS extant is 14470 (5th or 6th century) which lacks 2 Peter, 2 John, 3 John, Jude, Revelation, Hebrews.  However, we know that older MSS existed but have not survived.  However, a 10th century MSS has the complete NT.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_into_Aramaic